# Making a detached pipeline job to run job dependencies/needs

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is it possible for a job to run other job that it needs?
See example gitlab pipeline:

```
stages:
  - test
  - analysis

JacocoReport:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "test + jacoco"

SonarScan:
  stage: analysis
  needs: [JacocoReport]
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script: 
    - echo "sonar scan"
```

When I create merge request with such a configuration, I'll get

- one "normal" pipeline with just Jacoco
- one detached pipeline with just Sonar

What I'd like to have for detached pipeline is to run both Jacoco and Sonar, but **without** having to configure it in a way similar to:

```
JacocoReport:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script: 
    - echo "test + jacoco"
```

Is there any feature or feature-request for such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can circumnavigate this by adding workflow rule, to have only detached pipeline on merge requests.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

So it ends up as:

```
stages:
  - test
  - analysis

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    #TODO: scheduled 

JacocoReport:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "test + jacoco"

SonarScan:
  stage: analysis
  needs: [JacocoReport]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  script: 
    - echo "sonar scan"
```